# angularjs, need to transform object properties

Tags: javascript

In my angularjs application I have model which is array of objects as shown below:

```
 $scope.originalData = [{

     "id": 10000,
     "transactionid": "gec43434",
     "status": "COMPLETED",
     "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
     "errors": "1",
     "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35",
     "log_field": "Sample Text For Testing"

 }, {

     "id": 10001,
     "transactionid": "r34fdfdf",
     "status": "COMPLETED",
     "session_id": "dfdfer3453df",
     "errors": "3",
     "start_timestamp": "2016-10-07 03:20:15",
     "log_field": "Sample Text2 For Testing"

 }];
```

Now I need to modify the same array of objects to appear as shown below, except `log_field` remaining all properties should go under another property of the same object.

```
$scope.modifiedData = [{
     "subItems": {
         "id": 1000,
         "transactionid": "gec43434",
         "status": "COMPLETED",
         "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
         "errors": "1",
         "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35"
     },
     "log_field": "Sample Text For Testing"

 }, {
     "subItems": {
         "id": 10001,
         "transactionid": "r34fdfdf",
         "status": "COMPLETED",
         "session_id": "dfdfer3453df",
         "errors": "3",
         "start_timestamp": "2016-10-07 03:20:15"
     },
     "log_field": "Sample Text2 For Testing"

 }]
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you could do. using Array.map and delete.

```js
var originalData = [{
  "id": 10000,
  "transactionid": "gec43434",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
  "errors": "1",
  "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35",
  "log_field": "Sample Text For Testing"
}, {
  "id": 10001,
  "transactionid": "r34fdfdf",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "session_id": "dfdfer3453df",
  "errors": "3",
  "start_timestamp": "2016-10-07 03:20:15",
  "log_field": "Sample Text2 For Testing"
}];


var result = originalData.map((item) => {
  var log_field = item.log_field;
  delete item.log_field;
  return {
    "subItems": item,
    "log_field": log_field
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

In case,If you shouldn't modify the original data, here is what you could do.

```js
var originalData = [{
  "id": 10000,
  "transactionid": "gec43434",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
  "errors": "1",
  "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35",
  "log_field": "Sample Text For Testing"
}, {
  "id": 10001,
  "transactionid": "r34fdfdf",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "session_id": "dfdfer3453df",
  "errors": "3",
  "start_timestamp": "2016-10-07 03:20:15",
  "log_field": "Sample Text2 For Testing"
}];


var result = originalData.map((item) => {
  //Withou modifying original data.
  var resultItem = Object.assign({}, item),
    log_field = resultItem.log_field;
  delete resultItem.log_field;

  return {
    "subItems": resultItem,
    "log_field": log_field
  };
});
console.log(originalData);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough

```js
const originalData = [{"id":10000,"transactionid":"gec43434","status":"COMPLETED","session_id":"TTYUU455667","errors":"1","start_timestamp":"2016-11-07 02:35:35","log_field":"Sample Text For Testing"},{"id":10001,"transactionid":"r34fdfdf","status":"COMPLETED","session_id":"dfdfer3453df","errors":"3","start_timestamp":"2016-10-07 03:20:15","log_field":"Sample Text2 For Testing"}]

const doNotMap = 'log_field'
const modifiedData = originalData.map(d => {
  let subKeys = Object.keys(d).filter(key => key !== doNotMap)
  return {
    subItems: subKeys.reduce((obj, key) => {
      return Object.assign(obj, {
        [key]: d[key]
      })
    }, Object.create(null)),
    [doNotMap]: d[doNotMap]
  }
})

console.info('Modified =', modifiedData)
console.log('Original =', originalData)
```

---

So here's the not too different, pre ES2015 version

```js
var originalData = [{"id":10000,"transactionid":"gec43434","status":"COMPLETED","session_id":"TTYUU455667","errors":"1","start_timestamp":"2016-11-07 02:35:35","log_field":"Sample Text For Testing"},{"id":10001,"transactionid":"r34fdfdf","status":"COMPLETED","session_id":"dfdfer3453df","errors":"3","start_timestamp":"2016-10-07 03:20:15","log_field":"Sample Text2 For Testing"}]

var doNotMap = 'log_field'
var modifiedData = originalData.map(function(d) {
  var subKeys = Object.keys(d).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== doNotMap
  })
  var modified = Object.create(null)
  modified.subItems = subKeys.reduce(function(obj, key) {
    var keyObj = Object.create(null)
    keyObj[key] = d[key]
    return Object.assign(obj, keyObj)
  }, Object.create(null))

  modified[doNotMap] = d[doNotMap]
  return modified
})

console.info('Modified =', modifiedData)
console.log('Original =', originalData)
```

Comment: @Mahi an answer. ES2015 is supported in a lot of browsers now and babel takes care of the rest

Comment: i cannot upvote this . cuz i don't know if it is right or wrong

Comment: @Phil ES2015 is nice, but it's tough assumption that everyone is using it... I would stick to regular JS answers that everyone can use. If they're smart enough to port to ES6 then so be it.

Comment: no that's not right . what if you change original array or something  .

Comment: @Splurtcake not sure what you mean. ES2015 **is** regular JS

Comment: @Mahi I've added the original data to the output to show it's not mutated

Comment: @Phil babel is js library ?

Comment: @Phil Sure, but it requires a lot more to get it working across all browsers. And I'd almost bet that most people here haven't fully adopted it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach that will add all fields, regardless of your data structure. This is "slightly" future proof should your fields need to change. All fields will be added to `subItems` with the exception of `log_field`.

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 10000,
    "transactionid": "gec43434",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
    "errors": "1",
    "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35",
    "log_field": "Sample Text For Testing"
  },
  {
    "id": 10001,
    "transactionid": "r34fdfdf",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "session_id": "dfdfer3453df",
    "errors": "3",
    "start_timestamp": "2016-10-07 03:20:15",
    "log_field": "Sample Text2 For Testing"
  }
];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(object) {

  // Create a new temporary object
  var temp = {
    subItems: {}
  };

  // Loop through the existing object
  for (var key in object) {

    // Leave the log field out of sub items
    if (key === "log_field") temp[key] = object[key];

    // Add all other keys/values to the subItems object
    temp["subItems"][key] = object[key];
  }

  // Push the new object to the newData array
  newData.push(temp);
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Answers should contain the code. Links to external sites may supplement your answer but the important parts should be here on StackOverflow